# ApplicationSettings and Windows Forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, application-settings

I learned the technique described in this article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/29130/Windows-Forms-Creating-and-Persisting-Custom-User

The article's title is "**Windows Forms** - Creating and Persisting Custom User Settings in C#".
Also ApplicationSettingsBase class description on MSDN says

> Acts as a base class for deriving concrete wrapper classes to
>   implement the application settings feature in **Window Forms**
>   applications.

What does this technique have to do with Windows Forms if it perfectly works (seemingly) without any WinForms dependency in a simple console application?

Comment: Nothing; this answer can't really be answered, but my guess is the author created a Windows Forms app to demo this functionality. As you've noted, it's really something that comes from System.Configuration and System.Collections so it can be used in a wide variety of apps - console, winforms, asp.net, windows services, and so on.

Comment: But MSDN also mentions WinForms. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.applicationsettingsbase.aspx Why?

Comment: Again; speculative, but primarily because applications that store user settings tend to be GUI applications, hence Windows Forms, but could just as easily be ASP.Net. I wouldn't infer anything from it other than it is a common type of application where this example would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason that I can see is that the WinForms Form designer allows you to address the settings immediately:

[image: Storing the Form's location and text]

Storing the Form's location and text in the settings.

This is not mentioned in the tutorial you are referring to and a quite unknown feature.